# What is the simplest way to resolve definitions in a cloned repository?

Tags: git, variables

I've just cloned the DPDK repository which holds over 200 C header and source files. As I examine some of the source code, I find myself constantly confused by variable names and function calls.

In attempt to resolve them, I've resorted to two options:

1. I would begin by searching if this was a variable/function found in the current file by opening the respective file with vim and then typing `:?[Var/Func Name]` to see if the definition was there.
2. If this did not work, I would then resort to using `git grep [Var/Func Name]`, however over time this has shown ineffective due to the pages of results I receive.

Therefore, I was wondering what advice the community has for resolving the definitions of function or variable names in a such a vast repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git grep` supports regexp](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--E) (basic or POSIX extended)

You could use a regexp like

```
git grep -E "^myFunctionName\("
```

That would limit the results to those where the line starts with the function name, which seems to be the convention followed in a [`DPDK/dpdk`](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/d03d8622db48918d14bfe805641b1766ecc40088/drivers/net/iavf/iavf_rxtx.c#L1482-L1484) source code.